# What are these wavish patterns around atoms on microscopic images?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atoms, microscopy

This is an IBM movie about how they move single atoms: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSCX78-8-q0

There are often some "wavish" pattern around atoms on these pictures, like below some of them marked with red triangles:

[image]

Are these patterns real?

For example, it can be disturbances in sublayer? Or it can be observable quantum non-locality of atoms?

Or this can be just imperfection of microscopic device.

What is this?

Comment: perhaps the valence electrons in the copper background being attracting to the positively charged charged carbon nuclei

Comment: Why it is repeating multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are **Friedel Oscillations**. They occur because **the valance electrons moving freely in the metal, upon encountering the carbon atoms, are scattered by the impurity**. More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedel_oscillations). Here is a picture:

[image]

Very similar to the Friedel Oscillations in the question's picture:

[image]